# is it good to use async await in a function with 1 mongoose query?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am just confused if it's good to use async await in such cases:

```
import User from models/User

export const getUser = async (_id) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id })
  if (user) return user 
  return null 
}

export const getUser = async (_id) => {
   return await User.findOne({ _id })
}
```

Since mongoose return promise but I am just confused since with async, but here, it's only 1 query on db? unlike this:

```
export const getUser = async (_id) => {
   try { 
     const user = await User.findOne({ _id })
     const comments = await User.findOne({ _id })
     return { user, comments }
   } catch(e) {
     console.log('something went wrong', e)
     return null
   }
}
```

since it's 2 query then you have to await the 1st one then the 2nd, but when you have to await only 1 query, does it resolve?

Comment: Please clarify your question. `async/await` will wait for each time it's told to `await`. You can fire multiple promises off at once using Promise.all, but your question does not make sense. What do you mean by `when you have to await only 1 query does it resolve?`

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking, particularly with the question "does it resolve?" Both these methods could be improved, but I get the feeling that's not what you're confused about.

Comment: i am confused if it's good to use: const getUser = (_id) => return User.findOne({ _id }) when you only have 1 promise in a function, in this case since Model query is promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

async functions will always return  Promises, so there's really no need for async/await in the case of a single find().
Might as well do this:

```
export const getUser = (_id) => {
   return User.findOne({ _id })
}

...

getUser(aUserId).then(user => console.log(user))
```